# Use a for loop to split a a panel and plot some IDs

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, panel

I have a very large panel composed of many countries throughout many years.
For a sample, say I have

```
structure(list(country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Benin", 
"Burundi", "Cameroon", "Chile", "Cyprus", "Ecuador", "Equatorial Guinea", 
"Gabon", "Ghana", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", "India", 
"Jamaica", "Jordan", "Lebanon", "Liberia", "Madagascar", "Mali", 
"Mexico", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Nepal", "Nicaragua", "Niger", 
"Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Peru", "Rwanda", 
"Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sudan", "Togo", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
"Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = c("pseries", "factor"
)), date = structure(c(12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1965", "1966", "1967", 
"1968", "1969", "1970", "1971", "1972", "1973", "1974", "1975", 
"1976", "1977", "1978", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", 
"1984", "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", 
"1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", 
"2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", 
"2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), dist = c(-2.44153863355447, 
-0.565497304455015, 1.4222058591902, 1.18583114700364, 0.936095936859405, 
-0.40582369098349, 2.08296049774769, -1.59377116576285, 0.316969269882462, 
-0.562808458278515, -0.438155688763343, 0.824980940313303, -0.60293744113302, 
0.397182279339227, 1.34777053122572, 0.00539983501313633, 0.0528824118570846, 
-0.838507946421168, 0.220969370384196, -1.06945294612116, 0.157324834050942, 
0.244080457191975, 0.215931770884978, 0.226176571912671, 0.197663973781873, 
0.183399695771442, 0.334605869075331, 0.0683789169881243, -0.0432432418415798, 
-0.191834311017179, -0.368292801016647, -0.572222256415503, -0.838601784768107, 
-1.15213567684887, -1.49844386483361, 2.39265920977342, 1.90573467650352, 
1.3362714819111, 0.158391029649629, 1.12699318386612, 2.38996532864524
), dummy = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 400L, 
401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 405L, 406L, 407L, 408L, 409L, 410L, 411L, 
412L, 413L, 414L, 415L, 416L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to extract some countries and plot the variable "diff" for each of them.
In other words, I would like to create different, several plots, for a sample of countries out of  my panel.

I'm guessing I could start by

```
countries=c("Bangladesh", "Equatorial Guinea")

for (i in 1:length(countries)) {
  assign(countries[i],data_split[[i]])
 }
```

and then for the plots should be something similar, but I'm lost on the first part.

Comment: Leave the data the way it is and look into `facet_grid`

Comment: What kind of plots do you want to have, can you provide code for the plot? No need to split the data, we can plot the subset of the data, something like: `ggplot(d[ d$country %in% countries, ], ...) + geom_...`

Comment: The issue with using facet_grid is that I have too many countries. I would just like to plot some countries. 
I would like a simple plot, preferable one per country, where year is on the x axis and diff in the y axis.

```
ggplot(country[i], aes(x=year))+geom_line(aes(y=diff))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data using `split` and then loop over the components of that result. The below gives just a default `plot`, but you can adjust it if required.

```
data_split <- split(data, data$country)

for (country in names(data_split)) {
  country_data <- data_split[[country]]
  if (nrow(country_data) > 0) {
    plot(as.numeric(country_data$date), country_data$dist, main = country)
  }
}
```

That said, like the commenters noted, `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` is in my opinion a more elegant method to do the same. You can subset your data to select only the countries you want, before creating the plot.

Something like this:

```
countries <- c("Bangladesh", "Equatorial Guinea")
ggplot(data[data$country %in% countries, ], aes(as.numeric(as.character(date)), dist)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ country)
```

Comment: How would you do it using facet_grid or facet_wrap?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a `ggplot2` option